# Facebook SDK Like event not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

I'm trying to execute a FB.Event.subscribe after someone click on the like button:

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
            alert('I just clicked like button');
        });
    };
```

It works if I click on it without using ajax on the pagination, but for example, if click on Page 2, the Ajax reloads all the links (intended) and render the like&share buttons again, but if I click on like, the FB.Event.subscribe event won't work anymore.

I'm using

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    try{
        FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    }catch(ex){}
});
```

to render the buttons after an Ajax call.

Edit: I'm also using PHP with Yii.

I'm not 100% sure where exactly is the Ajax call, but the part that is being reloaded by ajax is that:

```
<section class="frame-content">
        <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'itemView' => '_view',
        ));
        ?>
    </section>
```

_view is the class that is being reloaded by ajax each time that someone click on any page from the pagination. The ajaxComplete is also inside _view class.

Comment: why would do that after someone clicked a like button? what is the use case? are you incentivizing likes somehow? either way, the ajax code would be important, especially the callback of the ajax code.

Comment: The reason is that the system has its own like button, so I wanted that the like button from facebook would count on the Like from the system too.

Comment: I don't understand why it is ignoring the FB.Event.subscribe after an ajax call...

Comment: why are you using ajaxComplete anyway? this is weird. again, show your ajax code. btw, i would suggest using the fetch api, not jquery. no one uses jquery anymore ;)

Comment: I'm trying to find the Ajax code, it's somewhere being called by the API.
Also, the reason that i am using ajaxComplete is because after an ajax call, all facebook Like icons dissapear, then I have to re-render them all, and the best way of doing it is waiting for all the ajax to finish and then I do FB.XFBML.parse() on ajaxComplete so it renders after everything is loaded.